# Jquery add sqoop value in html tag

Tags: php, jquery, select

This is my functions which get value from

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger popup" onclick="mySelectVal('<?php echo $row1['title'];?>','<?php echo $row1['returnReason'];?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130"></i>
</a>
```

i want to use functions values in options[value= **Value**] i am not good in jquery and english as well

```
function mySelectVal(res1, res2) {

    $('#stat1').change(function() {
        $('#row_dim')[($("option[value='"res1 "']").is(":checked")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
    });
}
```

i want to show my selected values in select menu item
i have two select input if first has value than second will show i want to do this thats way i made function and send arrg with in it 
i hope you will understand what i want to do

Comment: Do you mean `$("option[value='" + res1 + "']")`?

Comment: Yes Brother :) Thank you i made miner mistake

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a minor syntax mistake. When you want to use the content of a variable in the jquery pattern as options[value=**Value**], you need to concatenate the strings with the plus operator:

```
$('#row_dim')[($("option[value='" + res1 + "']").is(":checked")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
```